# How to efficiently get most recent elements from collection and preserve initial document structure

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, aggregation-framework

I am trying to perform following aggregation in MongoDB (using Kotlin) having following structure in db:

```json
{
    "_id" : 214134152323423
    "orderId" : 1,
    "createdAt" : 2000-01-01,
    "details" : "some very important note"
}
```

Now assuming I can have multiple documents with the same `orderId` but different `createdAt` date, I would like to take most recent documents and preserve initial document structure.

Right now I have:

```kotlin
mongoTemplate
  .aggregate(
    newAggregation(
      sort(
        Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdAt"
      ),
      group("orderId")
        .first("createdAt").`as`("createdAt")
        .first("details").`as`("details")
      ),
      "order-collection",
      String::class.java
   )
   .mappedResults
   .forEach { println(it) }
```

is this approach correct? Is it possible to do it without sorting the whole collection?

Comment: This approach will work, there's the obvious overhead of sorting the entire collection each time, it's hard to answer what I would change here without knowing more details.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert what other details do you need?

Answer (score 0):

### You need to use [On-Demand Materialized Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/)

The main idea: Periodically / each time when `order-collection` updates, you insert/refresh the `order-collection-view` pre-calculated data. This way, you have the recent order details and no need to scan the entire `order-collection`.